# Is there a way to analyse main effects on quantile mixed-effect regression in the spirit of the "ANOVA" procedure (now for medians)?

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, model-comparison, quantile-regression

I would like to analyse my data using quantile regression with random effect. The problem is I have also categorical covariates, which will "split" the output into corresponding levels. I would like to test the coefficients jointly, to assess the overall main effect of a covariate. Is there any method, ideally in R, that allows me to do that?

You know, something "in spirit of the ANOVA" in parametric models, which assesses the residual deviance, so I can compare nested models, and see if a removed effect changed something, but now dealing with quantiles (medians) rather than (predicted) means?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Unless you have interactions, main effects seem fairly straightforward to interpret